# how to upload multiple photos from netbeans to mysql

Tags: mysql, database

This is my initial code. when a button is clicked, the photos must be uploaded directly to the database..

```
private void browseActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       

JFileChooser chose=new JFileChooser();
chose.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES);
chose.setMultiSelectionEnabled(true);
int r=chose.showOpenDialog(new JFrame());
if(r == chose.APPROVE_OPTION){
String filepath= chose.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();
fp = filepath;
path.setText(filepath);
}// TODO add your handling code here:
}
```

Comment: so what happened ??

Comment: it just selects multiple photos from my computer.

Comment: once the photos are selected, another button must be clicked to store those photos to the database.